# Splitting SBT build

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an existing code base (Scala 2.9.3, sbt 0.12.2) and I would like to separate some of it to be a separate app. It is a multi project and the dependencies are like this:

- X
- A depends on X
- B depends on X
- etc..

The plan is to move A to be a standalone webservice with newer SBT and Scala versions. The first idea was to use 'git submodule' but what would be the best practice in SBT/Scala world to share code of subproject X?

Comment: Maybe use [SBT subprojects/multi-project build](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html)? Seems to fit the bill.

Comment: Publish X to a repository